# php loop on array to calculate entries from database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I have an arrays that are created from 2 database tables, `staff` and `time`.
The arrays look like this:

```
`array(44) { 
[0]=> string(2) "25" 
["id"]=> string(2) "12" 
[1]=> string(2) "12" 
["staff_id"]=> string(2) "12" 
[2]=> string(3) "9.6" 
["timein"]=> string(3) "9.6" 
[3]=> string(0) "" 
["onholiday"]=> string(0) "" 
[4]=> string(10) "2015-06-29" 
["dateadded"]=> string(10) "2015-06-29" 
[5]=> string(0) "" 
["ill"]=> string(0) "" 
[6]=> string(1) "1" 
["notes"]=> string(1) "1" 
[7]=> string(2) "12" 
[8]=> string(4) "name" 
["staff_name"]=> string(4) "name" 
}`
```

There are arrays with the same `staff_id`.
What I want to do is create a PHP loop that finds all the arrays with the same `staff_id` and calculate the `time_in` values.

I currently have

```
$sql = "SELECT *  
        FROM time, staff 
        WHERE dateadded BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate' 
        AND time.staff_id = staff.id 
        ORDER BY dateadded DESC;";
$result =  mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row['staff_name'];
}
```

But as you can see this is only very simple and gives back the list of names from the database.

My Database tables are as follows:
Staff:

```
id |staff_name|department_id
----------------------------
1  |Joe Bloggs|1
2  |John Smith|3
10 |staff3    |6
12 |name      |1
13 |Jo Bloggs |1
```

time:

```
id |staff_id|timein|onholiday|dateadded|ill|notes
-------------------------------------------------
12 |12      |3     |         |         |   |
13 |1       |6     |         |         |   |
14 |1       |4     |         |         |   |
15 |1       |7     |         |         |   |
16 |1       |7     |         |         |   |
17 |1       |7     |         |         |   |
18 |10      |7     |         |         |   |
19 |2       |7     |         |         |   |
20 |1       |8     |         |         |   |
21 |1       |7     |         |         |   |
22 |1       |7     |         |         |   |
23 |2       |8     |         |         |   |
24 |10      |9     |         |         |   |
25 |12      |9.5   |         |         |   |
```

Comment: Please use `mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` because it will be easier to work with your return array.

Comment: please post the table structure for both tables and let us know what you need to get from both, final result

Comment: Also please go read tutorials/php manual, because what you are asking for is a simple PHP script, that you would like someone to write for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you right this can be done using only SQL and no additional PHP:

```
SELECT staff.id, SUM(time.timein) As TimeIn
    FROM time, staff 
    WHERE dateadded BETWEEN '$startdate' AND '$enddate' 
    AND time.staff_id = staff.id
    GROUP BY staff.id;
```

I did some guessing when it comes to column names, so you will need to modify so it fits your DB. Read more about `GROUP BY` [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp).

Comment: Thanks @anders, this looks like it does the job. I cant upvote it because I dont have enough rep yet but I have accepted this and my answer.

Comment: Ah @anders Ive just realised that I am going to need to split the result into 4 weeks but this statement outputs the total. Is there a way I can use multiple between statements and output each result separately or is it more complex than that?

Comment: It is possible to do in SQL. Group not only by `staff.id`, but also by an expression returning the number of the week. On MySQL it would look something like `WEEK(dateadded)`. Read more about `WEEK` [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week).